# yarn: install local package from monorepo and use it inside docker image with offline cache

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules, yarnpkg, monorepo

My folder structure looks like this (monorepo):

```
project
|
+--- /api
|    |
|    +--- /.offline-cache
|    +--- /src
|    |    +--- index.js
|    |    +--- ...
|    |
|    +--- Dockerfile
|    +--- package.json
|    +--- yarn.lock
|
+--- /common
|    |
|    +--- /src
|    |    +--- index.js
|    |
|    +--- package.json
|
+--- /ui
|    |
|    +--- /.offline-cache
|    +--- /src
|    |    +--- index.js
|    |    +--- ...
|    |
|    +--- Dockerfile
|    +--- package.json
|    +--- yarn.lock
|
+--- docker-compose.yml
```

The offline-cache and building the docker-images for every 'service' (ui, api) are working.

Now I want to access/install the `common` module inside `api` and `ui` as well.
Running `yarn add ./../common` inside `/api` works and installs the module inside the `api` folder and adds it to `package.json` and `yarn.lock` file.
But when I try to rebuild the docker-image I get an error telling me

```
error Package "" refers to a non-existing file '"/common"'.
```

That's because there is no `common` folder inside the docker container and the installed package isn't added to the offline-mirror :(

I can't copy the `common` folder to the docker-image because it is outside the build context and I don't want to publish to NPM. What else can I do to get this working?

Comment: Hi @pkyeck , I am facing the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Himshwet moved all the Docker/yarn stuff up to the root-level so all folders are in the built-context and can be accessed in the Dockerfile

Comment: Thank you, i had tried the same solution, was hoping there might be a more elegant solution :)

Comment: Ah! Of course, this helped me debug further. I will try adding `cp ./the/package .` and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a [`context`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#context) in your `docker-compose.yml`, which does not need to be the same directory as your Dockerfile.

So you can create something like this:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:
  ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ui/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 'xxxx:xxxx'

  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 'xxxx:xxxx'
```

The same thing can be done with docker build as well, by adding the [`-f`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f) option, while running the command from the root directory.

```
docker build -f ui/Dockerfile xxxxxx/ui .

docker build -f api/Dockerfile xxxxxx/api .
```

You need to be aware, that you have to modify your `Dockerfile` slightly as well, to match the file structure of the project (using [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir)).

```
FROM node:18-alpine

# switch to root and copy all relevant files
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ui/ ./ui/
COPY ./common/ ./common/

# switch to relevant path (in this case ui)
WORKDIR /app/ui
RUN yarn && yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```